# UI getting blocked in deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, realm

i am fetching data from webservice using `HttpClient` and storing it into `Realm` database. My screen automatically starts the fetching data and showing `ActivityIndicator` till data gets loaded and stored in database.

Now the issue is , i have lot of data to be deserialized using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content)` as the data is huge this statement blocks/freezes my `ActivityIndicator` on UI screen.

how i can i deserialize object in background thread so that it doesn't block UI.

here is my code

```
 var response = await Service.createService<HttpResponseMessage>("HTTP").sendData(url, jsonData);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {

                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);
                        DB.createDB<EventType>("realm").subscribe();

                    if (responseData != null)
                        {
                            // status is ok
                            if (responseData.status.ToUpper() == OK)
                            {

                            MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage, EventType>(this, DB_EVENT, new EventTypeBuilder().status(true).requestType(url).response(responseData).Build());

                            }// status is error
                            else if (responseData.status.ToUpper() == ERROR)
                            {

                                MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage, EventType>(this, UI_EVENT, new EventTypeBuilder().status(false).requestType(url).errorMessage(responseData.errorMessage).Build());

                            }


                        }
                        else // when response is null

                            MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage, EventType>(this, UI_EVENT, new EventTypeBuilder().status(false).requestType(url).errorMessage(ERROR_RESPONSE_NULL).Build());


                    }
                    else
                    { // when some error occured
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


                    }
```

`Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);` blocks my thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it on its own thread and await the results:

```
Response responseData;
await Task.Run(() => 
{
     responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);
     // preform your Realm database add/updates, 
     // remember you are now on a different thread so get a new Realm Instance
});
```

Re: [Task.Run Method (Action)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0)

> Queues the specified work to run on the thread pool and returns a Task object that represents that work.

Comment: A bit simpler: `var responseData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content));`

Comment: Would also suggest `var responseData = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content)).ConfigureAwait(false);`